# BCM4311 wireless - works with B43 modprobe then stops - advice

Tags: 13.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I've been at whit's ends for over 4 months with this issue on my HP-550 laptop. Finally after 2 more hours today, found this solution (09/2013), but it doesn't appear to 'remember' once I reboot. Not sure how to fix it now as I've spent hours reading online.

Once I "Term" the below, my Wireless top right bar comes alive in 13.04 and connects to my network; once I reboot/turn off, I lose it and have to go back into Term and do the B43 Modprobe again, a pain.

Now I would like a really simple quick solution to the B43 Modprobe solution as listed below website: http://linuxg.net/how-to-fix-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/:

This is what they said:

Remove the default driver:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Install a the Linux Firmware nonfree drivers:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Load the b43 module:

```
$ sudo modprobe b43
```

To make it work automatically, do:

```
$ sudo su

cho "b43" >> /etc/modules
```

Help most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in one of your commands. Please do:

```
sudo su 
echo b43 >> /etc/modules 
exit
```

that should make the driver load on boot.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for that correction, I copied the original here from the listed link so presume the original on the page was incorrect. (-:

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing some leftover blacklist problems.  I find I don't need the b43 in /etc/modules at all.  Look in all the files in /etc/modprobe.d for the exact line "blacklist b43", and either comment it out with # or remove it.  Also, if ssb is blacklisted, it must also be removed or commented out (it is needed too).  Reboot and if you don't get the network, check what modules you did get with

```
lsmod | sort
```

and see what driver got picked up on the "cfg80211              208382  2 b43,mac80211"
line.  If you got wl instead of b43, you didn't remove things completely, so you should blacklist the wl driver in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.  Reboot and you should get the b43 driver loading.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I'll look into it and come back with my result for users here. Cheers.